# Can I create my own php.ini file?

Tags: cgi, php

My shared hosting service denies the ability to view errors in PHP in php.ini.

Hence, I want to write my own php.ini file and place it in my own subdirectory. Is this possible?

I have tried this tutorial to no avail. 
http://www.washington.edu/itconnect/web/publishing/php-ini.html#create

PHP just doesn't look for the php.ini file in my directory. It still adheres to the one at /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini.

Comment: Sorry about the wording of my question, but this really is a concern for me. I would really appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Well, is there any way I could turn error reporting on?

Comment: you might be able to enable errors using [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: Unless the global php.ini has been told to look in your private directory for a .ini file, then it won't look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ini_set` to [set the value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) of a given configuration option.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a .htaccess file to enable the error logging/reporting.

*.htaccess*

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

Comment: Guys if this is ignored due to php.ini settings let me know and i'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in the system php.ini following setting are there to enable user-defined INI files:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Name for user-defined php.ini (.htaccess) files. Default is ".user.ini"
user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"

; To disable this feature set this option to empty value
;user_ini.filename =
```